# Rust state-machine lexer

Tags: performance, rust, state-machine, lexical-analysis

I tried implementing a lexer in rust that peeks ahead at the next character and makes a decision based on that.
However, i am told that this is bad practice, and instead i should be using finite-state-machines.
However, my implementation is slower than the original lexer, going from 1MB per 20ms to 1MB per 50ms to 1MB per **80 milliseconds** running on debug mode.
Here is the code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
enum State {
    Start,
    Whitespace,
    Comment,
    Number,
    Ident,
    Slash,
    LeftArrow,
    RightArrow,
    End,
    NumberEnd,
    IdentEnd,
    Divide,
    Less,
    Greater,
    LeftShift,
    RightShift,
    Equal,
    LessOrEqual,
    GreaterOrEqual,
}

const ADVANCE: &[bool] = &[
    true,  // Start
    false, // Whitespace
    false, // Comment
    true,  // Number
    true,  // Ident
    true,  // Slash
    true,  // LeftArrow
    true,  // RightArrow
    false, // End
    false, // NumberEnd
    false, // IdentEnd
    false, // Divide
    false, // Less
    false, // Greater
    true,  // LeftShift
    true,  // RightShift
    true,  // Equal
    true,  // LessOrEqual
    true   // GreaterOrEqual
];

const TRANSITION: &[State] = &[
    // Start           Whitespace    Comment            Number            Ident            Slash           LeftArrow           RightArrow
    State::Ident,      State::Start, State::Comment,    State::NumberEnd, State::Ident,    State::Divide,  State::Less,        State::Greater,        // Letter
    State::Number,     State::Start, State::Comment,    State::Number,    State::Ident,    State::Divide,  State::Less,        State::Greater,        // Number
    State::Whitespace, State::Start, State::Comment,    State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Divide,  State::Less,        State::Greater,        // Whitespace
    State::Whitespace, State::Start, State::Whitespace, State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Divide,  State::Less,        State::Greater,        // Newline
    State::Slash,      State::Start, State::Comment,    State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Comment, State::Less,        State::Greater,        // Slash
    State::LeftArrow,  State::Start, State::Comment,    State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Divide,  State::LeftShift,   State::Greater,        // LeftArrow
    State::RightArrow, State::Start, State::Comment,    State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Divide,  State::Less,        State::RightShift,     // RightArrow
    State::Equal,      State::Start, State::Comment,    State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Divide,  State::LessOrEqual, State::GreaterOrEqual, // Equal
    State::End,        State::End,   State::End,        State::NumberEnd, State::IdentEnd, State::Divide,  State::Less,        State::Greater,        // Eof
];

pub struct Cursor<'a> {
    bytes: &'a [u8],
    pub start_pos: usize,
    pub pos: usize,
    state: State
}

macro_rules! test {
    ($name:tt, $($code:tt)*) => {
        {
            let now = std::time::Instant::now();
            $($code)*
            println!("{}: {:?}", stringify!($name), now.elapsed());
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    pub fn new(string: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self {
            bytes: string.as_bytes(),
            start_pos: 0,
            pos: 0,
            state: State::Start
        }
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    fn advance(&mut self) -> usize {
        let amount = if self.pos >= self.bytes.len() {
            8
        } else {
            match self.bytes[self.pos] {
                b'a'..=b'z' | b'A'..=b'Z' | 127.. => 0,
                b'0'..=b'9' => 1,
                b' ' | b'\t' | b'\r' => 2,
                b'\n' => 3,
                b'/' => 4,
                b'<' => 5,
                b'>' => 6,
                b'=' => 7,
                _ => todo!()
            }
        };
        State::End as usize * amount
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Cursor<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.state = State::Start;
        while self.state < State::End {
            if self.state == State::Start { self.start_pos = self.pos; }
            self.state = TRANSITION[self.advance() + self.state as usize];
            if ADVANCE[self.state as usize] {
                self.pos += self.bytes[self.pos].leading_ones().max(1) as usize;
            }
        }
        if self.state == State::End {
            None
        } else {
            Some(unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.bytes[self.start_pos..self.pos]) })
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let code = "1 ".repeat(1_000_000);
    let mut cursor: Cursor<'_> = Cursor::new(&code);
    //test! { Next, cursor.advance(); };
    test! {
        Cursor,
        while let Some(n) = cursor.next() {
            //println!("{n:?} length {:?}", n.len()); 
        }
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, (really fast parsing isn't my area), the idea behind lookup tables is to avoid branches and thus branch misprediction. So in order to make it really fast, you need to get rid of as many branches as possible in the parsing code.

You have a branch to decide whether to reset `start_pos`, a branch to decide whether to `ADVANCE`, as well as a `match` statement to classify the character class which possibly compiles to several branches.

It is probably worse than your previous attempt because the branch prediction worked better when you have different branches being tested in different parts of the lexer. Because this standardizes all the branches together, the branch predictor hasn't much of a hope.

But a more general issue is that if you want a really fast lexer built on a table like this, you probably don't want to build it by hand. You want to generate a lexer either using a crate like `logos` that builds a lexer for you or rolling your own generator. That way you can easily tweak the lexed language or the implementation strategy without completely rebuilding everything.